# How to extract a particular element/text inside an HTML using Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```html
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r=requests.get('https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xtse/enb/quote')
    c=r.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())

for item in soup.find("byId: {}".text):
print(item.text)
```

Once I ran that, on the bottom most of the whole html file it shows:

```html
window.__NUXT__=(function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N){J.id=1014028;J.title="Enbridge Expects a Rebound in 2021, Increases Dividend by 3%";J.deck=y;J.locale=K;J.publishedDate=L;J.updatedDate=L;J.paywalled=b;J.authors=[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}];J.authorDisclosure=[];J.body=[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"Wide-moat Enbridge announced 2021 full-year adjusted EBITDA guidance of CAD 13.9 billion-CAD 14.3 billion at its annual investor day on Dec. 8, which is above our previous forecasts. The midpoint of the guidance also implies a 6% increase from 2020 expected EBITDA. Enbridge believes that the increased performance will be driven by a recovery of Mainline volumes and the associated downstream pipelines; customer growth in the gas utilities business; rate increases on its gas pipelines; and the impact of new projects, including the Line 3 replacement. At this point, the Mainline’s heavy oil capacity is full, and demand for light capacity continues to increase. Accordingly, Enbridge expects first-quarter 2021 volumes to average 2.7 million barrels of oil per day, which is also above our previous expectations and compares favorably with 2.56 mmbbl\u002Fd in third-quarter 2020.",gated:a}],gated:a}];M.name=H;M.performanceId=A;M.secId=A;M.ticker=N;M.exchange=I;M.type=F;return {layout:"default",data:[{marketPrice:{value:43.55,filtered:a,date:{value:v,filtered:a}},premiumDiscount:{value:"-92.6",filtered:b,date:{value:v,filtered:a},text:{value:"Discount",filtered:a},type:{value:D,filtered:a}},threeStarRatingPrice:{value:"86.9",filtered:b},headquarterAddress1:{value:"425-1st Street SW",filtered:a},headquarterAddress2:{value:"Suite 200, Fifth Avenue Place",filtered:a},industry:{value:"Oil & Gas Midstream",filtered:a},stockStarRating:{value:"6",filtered:b,date:{value:v,filtered:a},text:{value:"Undervalued",filtered:a},type:{value:D,filtered:a}},fiscalYearEndDate:{value:"2020-12-31",filtered:a},headquarterState:{value:"AB",filtered:a},reportDate:{value:"2020-09-30",filtered:a},headquarterPostalCode:{value:"T2P 3L8",filtered:a},stewardshipRating:{value:"Bkwvsknl",filtered:b,date:{value:v,filtered:a}},companyProfile:{value:"Enbridge is an energy generation, distribution, and transportation company in the U.S. and Canada. Its pipeline network consists of the Canadian Mainline system, regional oil sands pipelines, and natural gas pipelines. The company also owns and operates a regulated natural gas utility and Canada’s largest natural gas distribution company. Additionally, Enbridge generates renewable and alternative energy with 2,000 megawatts of capacity.",filtered:a},fairValue:{value:"23.3",filtered:b,date:{value:"2020-12-08",filtered:a},type:{value:D,filtered:a}},fax:{value:"+1 403 231-5929",filtered:a},fiveStarRatingPrice:{value:"58.3",filtered:b},sector:{value:"Energy",filtered:a},economicMoat:{value:"Nsfq",filtered:b,date:{value:v,filtered:a}},ticker:N,website:{value:"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.enbridge.com",filtered:a},headquarterCountry:{value:"Canada",filtered:a},contactEmail:{value:"investor.relations@enbridge.com",filtered:a},fourStarRatingPrice:{value:"77.0",filtered:b},economicMoatTrend:{value:"Zcbqwh",filtered:b,date:{value:v,filtered:a}},headquarterCity:{value:"Calgary",filtered:a},phone:{value:"+1 403 231-3900",filtered:a},universe:{value:"EQ",filtered:a},exchange:I,totalEmployees:{value:11300,filtered:a},twoStarRatingPrice:{value:"54.91",filtered:b},fairValueUncertainty:{value:"Nnczrm",filtered:b},name:H,performanceId:A,secId:A,type:F,articles:[{title:"Epic Oil Crash Sets Up Brutal Downturn for Energy Sector",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F980350\u002Fepic-oil-crash-sets-up-brutal-downturn-for-energy-sector",caption:"But recovery is inevitable, and stocks look very cheap--just watch out for bankruptcy risk.",author:"Preston Caldwell",label:C,isVideo:a},{title:"Enbridge's Sell-Off Looks Exaggerated",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F978902\u002Fenbridges-sell-off-looks-exaggerated",caption:"The market is underestimating long-term cash flows once oil prices normalize.",author:c,label:z,isVideo:a},{title:"Executive Orders More Symbolic Than Material for Pipelines",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F923945\u002Fexecutive-orders-more-symbolic-than-material-for-pipelines",caption:"We're not changing our outlook for our midstream coverage.",author:"Stephen Ellis",label:C,isVideo:a},{title:"New Permit Moves Keystone XL Forward",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F922171\u002Fnew-permit-moves-keystone-xl-forward",caption:"Our fair value estimates for TransCanada and Enbridge are unchanged.",author:c,label:z,isVideo:a},{title:"Enbridge Hikes Dividend, Remains Deeply Undervalued",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F904922\u002Fenbridge-hikes-dividend-remains-deeply-undervalued",caption:"It has a wide moat and an attractive yield, and now's the time to invest.",author:c,label:z,isVideo:a},{title:"Concerns About Enbridge's Dividend Are Overblown",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F870105\u002Fconcerns-about-enbridges-dividend-are-overblown",caption:"The wide-moat company is on course to boost its dividend and offers hefty upside.",author:c,label:z,isVideo:a},{title:"Enbridge's Growth Portfolio Is Underappreciated",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F841990\u002Fenbridges-growth-portfolio-is-underappreciated",caption:"And the company continues to reward investors with annual dividend growth.",author:c,label:z,isVideo:a},{title:"Enbridge's Economic Moat Widens",link:"\u002Farticles\u002F565094\u002Fenbridges-economic-moat-widens",caption:"Shifting economics and supply dynamics provide growth opportunities.",author:"David McColl",label:C,isVideo:a}],analysis:{id:1014019,title:"Enbridge Increases Its Dividend by 3%",locale:K,publishedDate:B,updatedDate:B,paywalled:b,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],authorDisclosure:[],body:[],pillars:{investmentThesis:{title:"Business Strategy and Outlook",publishedDate:E,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],body:[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"Enbridge is an energy distribution and transportation company in the United States and Canada. It operates crude and natural gas pipelines, including the Canadian Mainline system. It also owns and operates Canada's largest natural gas distribution company.",gated:a}],gated:a}]},moat:{title:"Economic Moat",publishedDate:E,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],body:[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"Midstream companies process, transport, and store natural gas, natural gas liquids, crude oil, and refined products. There are multiple ways for midstream companies to build moats, but efficient scale is the dominant source. Hydrocarbons are produced and consumed in different places and in different forms from how they come out of the ground. Midstream firms transport and process hydrocarbons. Once a transport route is established, there's usually little need to build a competing route. Doing so would drive returns for both routes below the cost of capital. Thus, pipelines are generally moaty because they efficiently serve markets of limited size.",gated:a}],gated:a}]},managementAndStewardship:{title:"Stewardship",publishedDate:B,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],body:[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"President and CEO Al Monaco has been with Enbridge since 1995, serving in his current role since 2012. During his tenure at Enbridge, Monaco has experience in all business segments, international business development, corporate planning, and finance. His experience in various business segments, corporate development, growth projects, and finance positions him to successfully lead the proposed pipeline and gas distribution growth projects.",gated:a}],gated:a}]},enterpriseRisk:{title:"Risk and Uncertainty",publishedDate:E,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],body:[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"Enbridge’s profitability is not directly tied to commodity prices, as pipeline transportation costs are not tied to the price of natural gas and crude oil. However, the cyclical supply and demand nature of commodities and related pricing can have an indirect impact on the business as shippers may choose to accelerate or delay certain projects. This can affect the timing for the demand of transportation services and\u002For new gas pipeline infrastructure.",gated:a}],gated:a}]},valuation:{title:"Fair Value and Profit Drivers",publishedDate:B,authors:[{holdings:[o,p,q,r,s,t,k,u,n,m,l,j,i],id:h,name:c,jobTitle:g,byLine:f,shortBio:e,image:d,isPrimary:b}],body:[{type:w,contentObject:[{type:x,content:"Our fair value estimate of $43 (CAD 57) per share is based on a discounted cash flow model. We believe that Enbridge’s broad network of midstream assets and geographic diversification will serve it well in the low oil and gas price environment, and crude and natural gas pipeline expansions in growing regions will fuel EBITDA growth. Our cash flow forecasts incorporate the addition of the Line 3 replacement pipeline, but we adjusted our Canadian fair value downward to a reflect a risk-weighted probability of 80% that the pipeline is built.",gated:a}],gated:a}]},notes:J},notes:J},listedCurrency:{value:"CAD",filtered:a}},{}],error:y,state:{history:{currentRoute:"\u002Fstocks\u002Fxtse\u002Fenb\u002Fquote",previousRoute:y,returnRoute:y},ids:{byTicker:{"ST::XTSE::ENB":M},byId:{"0P0000681O":M}},markets:{movers:{gainers:[],losers:[],actives:[]},quotes:{},trailingReturns:{},intradayTimeSeries:{},lastRefreshed:y},player:{nowPlaying:y},siteAlert:{message:G,type:G},user:{userType:"visitor",isAdvisor:a,contentType:"e7FDDltrTy+tA2HnLovvGL0LFMwT+KkEptGju5wXVTU="}},serverRendered:b,serverDate:new Date(1607916811524)}}(false,true,"Joe Gemino","https:\u002F\u002Fim.mstar.com\u002FContent\u002FCMSImages\u002F78x78\u002F2008-jgemino-78x78.jpg","Joe Gemino, CPA, is a senior equity analyst for Morningstar.","Joe Gemino, CPA","Senior Equity Analyst","2008","MST50","SGDLX","FB","TRRNX","DODIX","DODGX","MORN","MOAT","AAPL","V","T","DIS","DODBX","2020-12-11","p","text",null,"Stock Strategist","0P0000681O","2020-12-08T18:13:00Z","Stock Strategist Industry Reports","Qual","2020-04-16T14:59:00Z","ST","","Enbridge Inc","XTSE",{},"en-US","2020-12-08T18:28:00Z",{},"ENB"));
```

My question: how do I extract the information inside "byID:" so that print(item.text) will give me "0P0000681O" only.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get a value, use a string find.

```
from simplified_scrapy import utils, SimplifiedDoc, req
html = req.get(
    'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xtse/enb/quote')

start = html.find('byId:{"')
html = html[start+len('byId:{"'):]
end  = html.find('":')
print(html[:end])
```

Result:

```
0P0000681O
```